# How to call a button onClick Method from another activity

Tags: android

I have two Activities named Main and Results.  In the main I have a START button that sends user entered data to a Bluetooth device, reads back measurement data from the BT device, processes the data and then graphs it in the Results activity.  In the Results activity I wish to have another START button that performs that exact same function so the user does not have to keep switching screens to take another measurement.  I made the START button in the Main activity static so I can call if from the Results activity.  This seems to work, but it keeps opening more Results activities every time the START button is pressed again. I tried to fix this by calling finish() each time the START button in the Results activity is pressed. This works, but causes the screen to flip back to the main activity briefly and then back to the Results activity once all the data is collected again. I would like to just stay on the Results activity and simply see the graphs change.

1.) I don't believe its good practice to have the static functions/variables.  Is there a better way to call this START method from another activity?

2.) Any suggestions on how to close the Results activity to avoid duplicates but keep the screen from changing back and forth quickly between the activities.

START method from Main Activity:

```
public static void start_sweep(View view) { 
    try{
        System.out.println("in start_sweep");
        What_Button =  0;
        start_freq = Double.parseDouble(start_freq_input.getText().toString());
        stop_freq = Double.parseDouble(stop_freq_input.getText().toString());;
        step_size = Double.parseDouble(step_size_input.getText().toString());;
        System.out.println(start_freq + " " + stop_freq + " " + step_size);
        short steps = (short) Math.round((stop_freq-start_freq)/step_size);
        _steps = (short) (steps + 1);
        gain = new double[_steps];
        phase = new double[_steps];
        int FTW_step = (int) (Math.round(step_size/CLK_freq*Math.pow(2, 32)));
        int FTW_start = (int) (Math.round(start_freq/CLK_freq*Math.pow(2, 32)));
        WriterThread wt = new WriterThread(mConnectThread.mmOutStream, steps, FTW_step, FTW_start);
        wt.start(); 
        start.setEnabled(false);
        NextBtn.setEnabled(true);
        NextBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.next_enabled);
        //Display state in "status" textview
        output.setText("Collecting Data...");

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        output.setText("Please Enter Sweep Parameters");

    }
}
```

Method called in Main Activity to start Results Actiivity:

```
    public void graphData() {
    //Creat X-axis array then pass it to Results and interleave with gain and phase
    X_axis = new double[_steps];
    X_axis[0] = start_freq;
    for (int i=1; i<_steps; i++) {
        X_axis[i] = X_axis[i-1] + step_size;
    }
    //start Results activity after button is pressed to display graph
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
    intent.putExtra("gainData", gain);
    intent.putExtra("phaseData", phase);
    intent.putExtra("Xaxis", X_axis);
    intent.putExtra("Battery Voltage", BatVolt);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

    startActivity(intent);
    start.setEnabled(true);
}
```

START method from Results activity:

```
    public void start_sweep2 (View view) {
    MainActivity.start_sweep(view);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the MainActivity (like a context) to the ResultsActivity so that it is calling the sweep method of the previous screen instead of just a sweep method from a new MainActivity(which is what is happening now)

Answer (score 0):

1 :There is No probelm in at all using the static functions but this function should return some data which can be used as for updating the views inside the activites , don't pass views inside the static functions.

2 : Write the static function inside any of these activity or in a seperate Class and call it directly using Class name and using result of the function update your view.